# What's the difference between `a: [b 1]` and `a: [b: 1]`, in red?

Tags: rebol, red

What is the difference between

```
a: [b 1]
; and
a: [b: 1]
```

both give the same results for

```
> a/b
1
```

they differ for `a/1` though.
When do you use what? And the 2nd is a set, what is the 1st?

Answer (score 9):

> the 2nd is a set, what is the 1st?

You can get answers by looking at the type:

```
>> type? first [b 1]
== word!

>> type? first [b: 1]
== set-word!
```

> What is the difference

When you use the expression `a/b` you are writing something that acts like a SELECT statement, looking up "any word type" matching `b` in the block indicated by `a`, then returning the item after it in the block.

Red follows heritage from Rebol--defaulting path selections to be the "non-strict" form of SELECT, which uses a "non-strict" form of equality

```
>> (first [a:]) = (first [a]) ;-- default comparison
true

>> select [b 1] (quote b)
== 1

>> select [b: 1] (quote b)
== 1
```

To get the strict behavior of telling the difference, you need to use the /CASE refinement (in the sense of "case-sensitive"):

```
>> (first [a:]) == (first [a]) ;-- strict comparison
true

>> select/case [b: 1] (quote b)
== none

>> select/case [b: 1] (quote b:)
== 1
```

Red seems to be at least a little more consistent about this than R3-Alpha, for instance honoring the equality of 1% and 0.01:

```
>> 1% = 0.01
== true ;-- both R3-Alpha and Red

>> select [0.01 "test"] 1%
== "test" ;-- in Red

>> select [0.01 "test"] 1%
== none ;-- in R3-Alpha
```

But it shows that there's a somewhat dodgy history behind equality semantics.

> When do you use what?

Good question.  :-/  Notation-wise in your source, you should use that which you feel most naturally fits what you want to express.  If you think a SET-WORD! is appropriate then use it, otherwise use a WORD!.  Implementation-wise, there are some nuances that are beyond the scope of a simple answer (locals gathering in FUNCTION, for instance).  If you know something will ultimately need to be transformed into an assignment, it may be helpful to use SET-WORDs.

Path evaluation is sketchy, in my opinion.  It arose as a syntactic convenience, but then produced a cross product of behaviors for every type being selected from every other type.  And that's to say nothing of the variance in how functions work *(what would `x: :append/dup/only/10/a` mean?)*

Small example: PATH! behavior in Rebol used a heuristic where if you are evaluating a path it will act as a PICK if the path component is an integer:

```
>> numbers: [3 2 1]

>> pick numbers 3
== 1 ;-- because the 3rd element is a 1

>> select numbers 3
== 2 ;-- because 2 comes after finding a 3

>> numbers/3
== 1 ;-- acts like PICK because (...)/3 uses an INTEGER!
```

...but as above, it will act like a SELECT (non-strict) if the thing being chosen is a WORD!:

```
>> words: [a b c]

>> select words 'a
== b ;-- because b is the thing after a in the block

>> pick words 'a
;-- In Rebol this is an error, Red gives NONE at the moment

>> words/a
== b ;-- acts like SELECT because (...)/a uses a WORD!
```

So the difference between SELECT and PICK accounts for that difference you're seeing.

It gets weirder for other types.  Paths are definitely quirky, and could use a grand unifying theory of some sort.

Comment: thanks a lot, a very in depth answer! I learned a lot (am still learning :))

Answer (score 2):

> And the 2nd is a set, what is the 1st?

It seems you are looking at both `[b 1]` and `[b: 1]` as code, but they are actually just data. More precisely, they are lists of two elements: a `word!` or `set-word!` value followed by an `integer!` value.

`a/b` is a syntactic sugar for `select a 'b`, which retrieves the value following `'b` word (using a `find` call internally). For convenience, the searching for `'b` also matches other word types:

```
red>> find [:b] 'b
== [:b]
red>> find [/b] 'b
== [/b]
red>> find ['b] 'b
== ['b]
red>> find [b] 'b
== [b]
```

As a side note, remember that a lit-word will evaluate to a word, which is sometimes referred by the "word-decaying" rule:

```
red>> 'b
== b
```

`/case` refinement for `find` and `select` will apply a stricter matching, ensuring that the types are also the same. Though, you obviously cannot use it with path notation, you would need to replace the path with a `select/case` call instead.

So, both are giving the same result for `a/b`, because both will return the value following `b` word (regardless of his "word sub-type"):

```
red>> [b 1] = [b: 1]        ;-- loose comparison, used by `find` and `select`.
== true
red>> [b 1] == [b: 1]       ;-- strict comparison, used by `find/case` and `select/case`.
== false
```

> they differ for a/1 though.

Integer values have specific semantics in paths. They act as sugar for `pick`, so `a/1` is equivalent to `pick a 1`. You can also force that behavior other words referring to integers in paths, by making them `get-word!` values:

```
red>> c: 1
== 1
red>> a: [b 123]
== [b 1]
red>> a/:c
== b
red>> a: [b: 123]
== [b: 123]
red>> a/:c
== b:
red>> c: 2
== 2
red>> a/:c
== 123
```

Read more about paths from Rebol Core Manual: http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html#section-2.10

> When do you use what?

For `a/b` vs `a/1` usage, it depends if you want to achieve a `select` or a `pick` operation.

For `[b 1]` vs `[b: 1]`, it depends on the later use of the block. For example, if you are constructing a block for serving as an object or map specification, then the set-word form is a better fit:

```
red>> a: [b:]
== [b:]
red>> append a 123
== [b: 123]
red>> c: object a
== make object! [
    b: 123
]
```

Also, you should use the set-word form each time you imply a "key/value" relationship, it makes your intent clearer for yourself and other readers as well.

Comment: `you should use the set-word form each time you imply a "key/value" relationship` this was the aha-moment for me, thanks for the details

Comment: @WolframKriesing Thanks for the feedback, I will put more emphasis on that aspect in the Red documentation.